# Erro em contador de caracteres de uma matriz

Tags: c

Preciso fazer um contador de ocorrências de uma matriz, pelo Visual Studio, e estou indo até bem, porém quando tento executar o programa, ocorre um erro e não sei como resolver.

**O erro que ocorre é o seguinte:** Exceção gerada em 0x00981C28 em Matriz.exe: 0xC0000005: violação de acesso ao ler o local 0x040FD8F8.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char matriz[3][3], c;
    int linhas, colunas;

    int matrizAux[100], ascii[255], r;
   
    printf("Digite a quantidade de linhas da matriz: "); 
    scanf_s("%d", &linhas);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf("Digite a quantidade de colunas da matriz: "); 
    scanf_s("%d", &colunas);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Digite um valor para os elementos da matriz\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++)
        {
            printf("Elemento[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf_s("%c", &matriz[i][j]);
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++)
        {
            printf("%c\t", matriz[i][j]); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\n\n");

    //Zerando Tabela ASCII
    for (r = 0; r < 255; r++) {
        ascii[r] = 0;
    }

    //Transformando caracteres em inteiros (ASCII)
    for (r = 0; r < linhas && r < colunas; r++) {
        matrizAux[r] = int(matriz[r]);
    }

    //Contar quantidade de vezes
    for (r = 0; r < linhas && r < colunas; r++) {                       // Roda por todos os espaços 
        if (matrizAux[r] != 32) {                            // Retirar espaços da contagem
            ascii[matrizAux[r]]++;   //ERRO OCORRE AQUI
        }                             // Guardando quantidade de vezes que os caracteres se repetem
    }

    //Imprimindo repetidos
    for (r = 0; r < 255; r++) {
        if (ascii[r] > 0) {      //Verifica se é maior quer 0 
            printf("O caractere %c apareceu %d vez(es) na matriz\n", r, ascii[r]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

[image: Código do erro da matriz]

Comment: Uai, que estranho... Como que seu código emite exceções se vc está programando em C? Nunca vi isso.

Comment: Você declarou matriz como um array bidimensional mas aqui: `matrizAux[r] = int(matriz[r]);` informa um único índice, me parece que está errado. Outra coisa é que você declara um array 3x3 mas não faz nenhuma consistência ao ler as variáveis `linhas` e `colunas`, não seria melhor declarar o array após ler as referidas variáveis?

Answer (score 0):

n uso VS(então n posso reproduzir exatamente o erro desse codigo), mas pelo "violação de acesso ao ler" e vendo o codigo deduzo q seja:

1 - `matriz[3][3]`
e depois no codigo

```
    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < colunas; j++)
            scanf_s("%c", &matriz[i][j]);
```

vc declara a matriz 3x3 mas usa ela como linhas x colunas, pode ocorrer de linhas ou colunas ser maior que o tamanho 3 que foi declarado(acesso invalido)

o ideal seria ou usar tamanho de matriz fixo, ou alocação de memoria dinamica

```
char **matriz = malloc (linhas * sizeof (char*)) ;
for (i=0; i < linhas; i++)
   matriz[i] = malloc (colunas * sizeof (char)) ;
```

2 - `matrizAux[r] = int(matriz[r]);` é uma matriz e voce só esta percorrendo uma dimensão, em C tera que percorrer cada um de todas as posições da matriz